# Hibernate event in post update not working at all

Tags: java, hibernate

I created an Hibernate event to be run after an update, but it's not called. What's wrong?

This is my setting in the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<event type="post-update">
    <listener class="com.zoox.ExampleTrigger"/>
</event>
```

And this is my listener:

```
package com.zoox;

import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostUpdateEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostUpdateEventListener;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PreUpdateEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PreUpdateEventListener;

public class ExampleTrigger implements PostUpdateEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {

    }
}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Try using lifecycle callback methods.
Try @PostUpdate.